# Statistical significance between group sums

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, sum

How can we state that there is a significant difference between total amounts of donations of two sample groups in the following scenario.

Control group A has donated lots of smaller denominations like one-dollar bills totaling to 112 dollars. Test group B donations are much meatier but on the other hand the number of donations is a lot smaller bringing the total up to 120 dollars.

Both groups were of size 1000, meaning that group A had 968 and group B had 989 people who donated 0 dollars.

Is it safe to conclude that going forward the test group B will in the long run bring in more money than the control group A?

Here's the data:

```
grp <- rep('a',32)
grp <- append(grp,rep('b',11))
grp <- append(grp,rep('a',968))
grp <- append(grp,rep('b',989))
don <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,5,5,5,5,5,10,10,20,20)
don <- append(don,c(5,5,5,5,10,10,10,10,20,20,20))
don <- append(don,rep(0,1957))
df <- data.frame(grp,don)
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by a "winner." If in fact these are all the donations that have been collected, and the "winner" is the larger total, then the dispute is settled by comparing the two sums. Since you haven't availed yourself of that simple solution, apparently you have some other concept of "winner" in mind--but what is it, exactly?

Comment: Let me clarify this. It's an A/B test where groups A and B represent samples, not populations, call them a control group and a test group respectively. Control group was approached with one tactic for donations and test group was approached with another tactic. So, the question is whether the test tactic will continue bringing in more money than the original tactic. Because these are samples I don't think that a mere comparison of sums is enough. To me it's not obvious that the test tactic will necessarily bring in more money over a long run. Hopefully the problem at hand became more clearer.

Comment: Because that is essential information to understand your question, please incorporate it in your post.  (You can edit it.)

Comment: Do you know how many people gave $0 in each group? Your data only has those who gave money. You won't be able to come to much of a meaningful conclusion with this data. What it would say is, "If people gave money, they tended to give more money when they encountered our manipulation." That is not the same as saying that people in group B on average gave more money than group A.